pyproj.Transformer.from_pipeline inverse / Using EPSG transformation code how to invert?
I have been trying to use PROJ as an an alternative confirmation of correct parameters when doing transformations (either by spreadsheet or third party software). Typically we will get instructed by our clients what transformation to use, regardless of what is picked as the most suitable transformation when supplying CRS to PROJ on the command line.
To that end have been doing some testing on ED50 (EPSG:4230) to WGS84 (EPSG:4326) where I specifically want to use the transformation parameters ED50 to WGS84 (24), Norway Offshore S62 which are EPSG:1613.
OK, so I can use the following to find the PROJ pipeline:
projinfo -s EPSG:4230 -t EPSG:4326 --spatial-test intersects

Which determines that it is 'Operation No. 18'.
Now, I understand that there are two ways of doing this in pyproj, either using the entire pipeline output or stating the transformation code as below:
    import pyproj
    
    # Create a transformer using the specified pipeline
    transformer = pyproj.Transformer.from_pipeline("EPSG:1613")
    
    # Function to transform coordinates
    def transform_coords(lat, lon, height):
        transformed_lon, transformed_lat, transformed_height = transformer.transform(lon, lat, height)
        return transformed_lat, transformed_lon, transformed_height
    
    # Example coordinates in EPSG:4230 (ED50)
    latitude, longitude, height = 58, 5, 100
    
    # Transform the coordinates
    transformed_lat, transformed_lon, transformed_height = transform_coords(latitude, longitude, height)
    print(f"{transformed_lat:.11f}  {transformed_lon:.11f} {transformed_height:.11f}")

However, I cannot see a way to use the inverse of this transformation?
For reference, I can also use the full pipeline as below to get the same result:
    import pyproj
    
    # Define the PROJ pipeline string for the specific operation
    pipeline = (
        "+proj=pipeline "
        "+step +proj=axisswap +order=2,1 "
        "+step +proj=unitconvert +xy_in=deg +xy_out=rad "
        "+step +proj=push +v_3 "
        "+step +proj=cart +ellps=intl "
        "+step +proj=helmert +x=-90.365 +y=-101.13 +z=-123.384 +rx=0.333 +ry=0.077 +rz=0.894 +s=1.994 +convention=position_vector "
        "+step +inv +proj=cart +ellps=WGS84 "
        "+step +proj=pop +v_3 "
        "+step +proj=unitconvert +xy_in=rad +xy_out=deg "
        "+step +proj=axisswap +order=2,1 "
    )
    
    # Create a transformer using the specified pipeline
    transformer = pyproj.Transformer.from_pipeline(pipeline)
    
    # Function to transform coordinates
    def transform_coords(lat, lon, height):
        transformed_lon, transformed_lat, transformed_height = transformer.transform(lon, lat, height)
        return transformed_lat, transformed_lon, transformed_height
    
    # Example coordinates in EPSG:4230 (ED50)
    latitude, longitude, height = 58, 5, 100
    
    # Transform the coordinates
    transformed_lat, transformed_lon, transformed_height = transform_coords(latitude, longitude, height)
    print(f"{transformed_lat:.11f}  {transformed_lon:.11f} {transformed_height:.11f}")

Of course, I can now just look up the full pipeline again by flipping the CRS to get the inverse parameters:
projinfo -s EPSG:4326 -t EPSG:4230 --spatial-test intersects

But in the first pyproj example code (which seems a way more elegant solution) how do I tell the operation to use the inverse?
Based on the answers below have updated as follows, flipping some parameters Lat/Long to maintain continuity
import pyproj

# Workflows need reviewing of CRSes axis count and order
for auth_id in ["EPSG:4230", "EPSG:4326"]:
    crs = pyproj.crs.CRS(auth_id)
    print(f'{crs.name = }')
    for i, axis in enumerate(crs.axis_info):
        print(f'{i = }; {axis.name = }')

# Create a transformer using the specified pipeline
transformer = pyproj.Transformer.from_pipeline("EPSG:1613")

# Function to transform coordinates
def transform_coords(lat, lon, direction="FORWARD"):
    transformed_lat, transformed_lon = transformer.transform(lat, lon, direction=direction)
    return transformed_lat, transformed_lon

# Example coordinates in EPSG:4230 (ED50)
latitude, longitude = 58, 5

# Transform the coordinates
transformed_lat, transformed_lon = transform_coords(latitude, longitude, "FORWARD")
print(f"{transformed_lat:.11f} {transformed_lon:.11f}")


To define the direction of a pyproj.Transform.transform() method, use its direction parameter.
You can pass the "FORWARD" or "INVERSE" strings as argument, as their pyproj.enums.TransformDirection attribute.
import pyproj

# Workflows appreciate reviewing CRSes axis count and order
for auth_id in ["EPSG:4230", "EPSG:4326"]:
    crs = pyproj.crs.CRS(auth_id)
    print(f'{crs.name = }')
    for i, axis in enumerate(crs.axis_info):
        print(f'{i = }; {axis.name = }')

# Create a transformer using the specified pipeline
transformer = pyproj.Transformer.from_pipeline("EPSG:1613")

# Function to transform coordinates
def transform_coords(lat, lon, height, direction="FORWARD"):
    transformed_lon, transformed_lat, transformed_height = transformer.transform(lat, lon, height, direction=direction)
    return transformed_lat, transformed_lon, transformed_height

# Example coordinates in EPSG:4230 (ED50)
latitude, longitude, height = 58, 5, 100 #Not really because it is 2D CRS

# Transform the coordinates
transformed_lat, transformed_lon, transformed_height = transform_coords(latitude, longitude, height)
print(f"{transformed_lat:.11f}  {transformed_lon:.11f} {transformed_height:.11f}")


# Example coordinates in EPSG:4326 (WGS84)
latitude, longitude, height = 58, 5, 100 #Not really because it is 2D CRS

# Transform the coordinates
transformed_lat, transformed_lon, transformed_height = transform_coords(latitude, longitude, height, "INVERSE")
print(f"{transformed_lat:.11f}  {transformed_lon:.11f} {transformed_height:.11f}")

